# How to do a time dependent loop for different initial conditions

Tags: differential-equations, date-and-time, infinite-loop

I would like to do a loop for this problem, this is my code

```
Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234]

dt = 2;  (*\[Delta]t para saber cuantas parte partir el desorden, \
condición es que tmax/dt siempre debe ser un entero*)

tini = 0;

tmax = 20;

Nmax = 5; (*Number of sites*)

loc = 10 Nmax; (*localization length in the center ban*)

I\[Sigma]2 = 8/loc // N(*Variance*)
(*0.16*)

ra = 1; (*coupling range*)

n0 = 5;

\[Psi]ini = Table[KroneckerDelta[n0 - i], {i, 1, Nmax}];

RRR = RandomReal[{-Sqrt[3*\[Sigma]2], Sqrt[3*\[Sigma]2]}, {tmax/dt, 
    Nmax}];

Z[n_] := Table[
   Sum[KroneckerDelta[i - j + k], {k, 1, ra}] + 
    Sum[KroneckerDelta[i - j - k], {k, 1, ra}], {i, 1, Nmax}, {j, 1, 
    Nmax}] + DiagonalMatrix[RRR[[n]]]

usol[1] = 
  NDSolveValue[{I D[\[Psi][t], t] == 
     Z[1].\[Psi][t], \[Psi][0] == \[Psi]ini}, \[Psi], {t, 0, dt}];

usol[2]=
  NDSolveValue[{I D[\[Psi][t],t]\[Equal]Z[2].\[Psi][t],\[Psi][
      0]\[Equal]usol[1][2]},\[Psi],{t,2,4}];

usol[3]=
  NDSolveValue[{I D[\[Psi][t],t]\[Equal]Z[3].\[Psi][
       t],\[Psi][0]\[Equal]usol[2][4]},\[Psi],{t,4,6}];

usol[4]=
  NDSolveValue[{I D[\[Psi][t],t]\[Equal]Z[4].\[Psi][t],\[Psi][
      0]\[Equal]usol[3][6]},\[Psi],{t,6,8}];
```

My try was this of to get the loop, first solve with the initial condition [Psi]ini and then take a loop with command "Do" but it does not work. The point here is create a loop which take the initial condition of the before solution evaluate in the maximal time for this solution (usol), I do not know how introduce in a loop another solution.

```
usol[1] = 
  NDSolveValue[{I D[\[Psi][t], t] == 
     Z[1].\[Psi][t], \[Psi][0] == \[Psi]ini}, \[Psi], {t, 0, dt}];

Do[{usol[n] = 
   NDSolveValue[{I D[\[Psi][t], t] == Z[n].\[Psi][t], \[Psi][0] == 
      usol[n - 1][n dt]}, \[Psi], {t, (n - 1) dt, n dt}]}, {n, 2, 
  tmax}]
```

Then I would like to join all the solutions and plot them together.

Comment: The initial condition in the loop should be `\[Psi][0] == usol[n - 1][(n - 1) dt]`?

Comment: @tueda It was my tried, the point is to take a new initial condition in each new differential equations where the first initial condition is \[Psi]ini for usol[1] and for solve usol[2] I want the initial condition usol[1][(n-1)dt] where (n-1)dt is the maximal time where is defined usol[1], the next step is solve usol[3] with initial condition usol[2][tmax] evaluated in the maximal time of usol[2] is defined and so on.